# I want my website to accept bitcoins without dealing with security issues

Tags: security, ecommerce, payment-processors

I want my site to accept bitcoins (and automatically reward users with it), but do not want to deal with the security issues that would entail.
Is there a SaaS (Software as a Service) which could handle all the hassle for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest integrating **https://bitpay.com/**
They charge you like any other service but they do all the payment stuff. Also they have plugins for most open source shopping carts [Bitpay plugins](https://bitpay.com/bitcoin-shopping-cart-plugins)
Also keep you wallet offline to avoid problems.

Comment: I want to automatically reward users for doing certain actions, so I guess keeping wallet offline is not going to work. The second question is how much can I trust bitpay?

Comment: You can trust them in a way you trust any other payment gateway...How do you know that paypal will not disappear tomorrow with you funds? Bitpay is the largest bitcoin payments gateway [read this article](http://bitcoinmagazine.com/bitpay-receives-another-round-of-venture-capital-funding/)

Keeping wallet online is very insecure, I would at least keep it away from the server and only connect to central database to get list of transaction to send.

Comment: @Moonwalker - Wordpress and Mega both use Bitpay to accept bitcoin payment.  I think Namecheap does also.

Answer (score 1):

Coinapult has an API that you can use to send coins to a user's mobile SMS/text number or via e-mail.

It's not really the right way to do it but it is one way of doing it.

You could also do it by distributing an Instawallet URL.   The person that knows the Instawallet URL can spend the funds.

Redeemable codes would be another method.  You can hand out Mt. Gox redeemable codes denominated in BTCs.  The user needs to create a Mt. Gox account to redeem the voucher though.

You could also distribute a private key like what is done for [Paper bitcoin wallets](http://bitaddress.org).  The methods for redeeming those are not user friendly though.